# Geodistance function doesn't change output when input changed

Tags: php

I have a PHP Function which calculates the distance between two sets of long and lat coordinates. The initial input is supplied from the user (I will prevent SQL injection later...) in postcode form, to which I have a database which looks up the postcode, and retrieves the long and lat.

For testing purposes I have echoed the long and lat values relating to the postcode, and these do change each time I resubmit the form. However the distance in miles doesn't change, whatever postcode I use in the UK I get "3559.8580109981 " as the output.

The function:

```
function calculateDistance($latitude1, $longitude1, $latitude2, $longitude2) {
$theta = $longitude1 - $longitude2;
$miles = (sin(deg2rad($latitude1)) * sin(deg2rad($latitude2))) + (cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)));
$miles = acos($miles);
$miles = rad2deg($miles);
$miles = $miles * 60 * 1.1515;
return $miles; 
}

$point1_lat ='51.52488120000000000'; // preset for testing
$point1_lng ='-0.09101110000005974'; // preset for testing
$point2_lat = $row['latitude'];;
$point2_lng = $row['longitude'];

//Function call with the coordinates.
$miles = calculateDistance($point1_lat, $point1_lng, $point2_lat,$point2_lng);

echo '<br>Nautical Miles : '.$miles;    // This stays the same, irrelevant of postcode entered.
```

Comment: What are the values in `$row['latitude']` and `$row['longitude']`?

Comment: They are supplied from a postcode, which I retrieve using "$postcode = $_GET['l'];" This is then queried in a database (full of UK postcodes with long and lat) and echoed on screen for testing. The lat and long do change (as I can see) however the "Nautical Miles" do not.

Comment: Interesting... When I manually enter the Long and Lat values, I get a valid output. However when I use $_GET to find the corresponding values of the supplied postcode (which is in the correct format) it doesn't work.

Comment: remove the `'` single quotes from around your `$point1_lat` and `$point1_lng` values ?

Comment: Hasn't solved the issue, thanks for pointing that out though, completely missed it!

Comment: what contains in `$row['latitude']` and `$row['longitude']`? try `exit($row['latitude'] . ';' . $row['longitude']);`

Comment: The user enters a postcode, which is then used to select the corresponding long and lat from the database - so it depends on the postcode. How would I use "exit($row['latitude'] . ';' . $row['longitude']);" when I manually declare both variables ($point2_lat and lng)?

Comment: Just add this before line `//Function call with the coordinates.`

Comment: The values in $row['latitude'] and $row['longitude'] are evidently both 0. You are calculating the distance from London to 0E, 0N, which is in the sea near West Africa.

Comment: I added "exit($row['latitude'] . ';' . $row['longitude']);" however I just get a blank screen. And they aren't 0 because I have echoed the values and can confirm that they contain a long and lat that is based in the UK. SL1 4ST -0.625298580548549 51.525937126715800 are the values.